# Possilble to keep ID fields when resampling pandas datetimeindex?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set with a datetimeindex and 2 columns, ['WorkoutID', 'power'].

The datetimeindex is at the daily level, but I am trying to resample to the weekly level and get the max power from all workouts within each week:

```
df['best_power'] = df['power'].resample('D').max()
```

Right now the output of this gives me the datetimeindex at the weekly level and the max power ('best_power'), but it drops the workoutID column.

I want to also be able to see what workoutId that max power is coming from - how can I retain the workoutID column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `idxmax` with `groupby`

```
df.loc[df.groupby(df.index.strftime('%Y-%w')).power.idxmax()]
```

Comment: This may work, but doesn't really answer the question because you're not using the `resample()` function.  For weeks it may be fine, but for more granular time periods, it's probably not ideal.